# How to import Groovy annotations on vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, groovy, classpath

I am new to Groovy and I was following some tutorial that was using IntelliJ but I was writing the code in VS Code. Everything so far has been running correctly but I cannot figure out how to get the annotations to work.

The error I get when I run my code is:

```
[Running] groovy "/Users/echodrome/dev/Groovy/HelloWorld.groovy"
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/Users/echodrome/dev/Groovy/Person.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class ToString for annotation
 @ line 1, column 1.
   @ToString
   ^

1 error
```

The entire Person class looks like this

```
@ToString
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    int age
    String getFullName() {
        firstName + " " + lastName
    }
}
```

The HelloWorld class only creates the user and tries to run a couple of asserts but it doesn't seem to be important for this error.

Is this a Groovy library issue? a VS Code missing path issue?

Comment: Well as you expected, there is an import missing. If your IDE can not automatically import things, you will be in a rough spot.  You can use the official docs and figure that out for yourself, but at that point, you could as well just use some regular editor (btw: `import groovy.transform.ToString` shoud do the trick here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the annotation to `@groovy.transform.ToString`, the error goes away:

[image]